# Migration a has_and_belongs_to_many join table don't create the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm develop a web app with Rails 3.0.9 and Postgres 9.4
I'm trying to create a join table for a has_and_belongs_to_many association, but when execute "rake db:migrate" the only one not executed migration is the migration for join table.
Rails didn't show any error, only didn't create the table.
When I do the rollback, rails show a error because couldn't drop the table because don't exist.

Here is the code of migration:

```
class CreateCampanaLocalJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    def change
      create_table :campanas_locals, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :campana_id
        t.integer :local_id
      end
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :campanas_locals
  end
end
```

Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: you've nested a method definition within your up method. Doesn't this never really execute the change method as it's just the definition of that method, not a call of it?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.0.X try:

```
class CreateCampanaLocalJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :campanas_locals, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :campana_id
      t.integer :local_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :campanas_locals
  end
end
```

Rails 3.1.X try:

```
class CreateCampanaLocalJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :campanas_locals, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :campana_id
      t.integer :local_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had tried 3.0.x and 3.1.X format already, but neither work. I have 2 migrations for 2 has_and_belongs_to_many associations and both have the problem. I'm create the tables by hand for keep working, the associations works, but the migrations didn't work. Thanks